# Instantiate map from directive AngujarJs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs, singleton

I've made a directive to load up the google maps api on my site: http://plnkr.co/edit/3009kInkBmiF9ksB3eg9?p=catalogue

My question is: how would it be the best way to instantiate the map to then add some click listeners on diferent views?

I'm using the ngView directive to load a secondary view:

```
'use strict';

var climbingApp = angular.module('climbingApp', ['ngRoute', 'maps'], 
    function( $routeProvider ){

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'Main'
        });

        $routeProvider.when ('/newSector', {
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/newSector.html',
            controller: 'addSector'
        });
    }
);
```

And within the newSector controller I use a service to add the listener:

```
climbingApp.factory('Markers', function( $rootScope ){
    return {
        addListener: function( mapInstance, callback ) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
                mapInstance,
                'click',
                 function( e ) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: e.latLng,
                        map: mapInstance
                    });
                    $rootScope.$apply( function(){ callback( e ); });
                }
            );
        }
    }
});
```

But doing this way I can't remove the listener from within the Main controller because I can't refer to the map instance. Any clue how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the creator of [ng-map, google maps angularjs directive](https://github.com/allenhwkim/ng-map) called, ng-map. This does not require any Javascript coding for simple functionality.

For your case, with that directive, you can just add 'on-click' attribute to `map` tag.

```
<map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]" on-click="myfunc()">
</map>`
```

More detail can be found at [ng-map](https://github.com/allenhwkim/ng-map).